# Push Notification settings in IOS 7

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios7

How to check if PushNotification for application is enabled ?

I knew we can change the push notification settings for application via settings->notification.

Here how to check this in appcode in IOS 7?

Comment: Be aware that iOS7 and Xcode 5 are still under NDA which restricts you from talking about them outside of the official Apple Developers Forum.

Comment: cool ill raise it apple forum thanks for mentioning

Comment: Ok then how to check it in IOS 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you’ve registered Push Notifications (asked the user if he allows…)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

you can check what types of push notifications are enabled:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType enabledTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

I hope this is what you want…

Comment: Are you testing on the device? Simulator does not support Push Notifications

Comment: Yes I am testing it in device.